# How to change IP address with Selenium using Tor everytime I make a request

Tags: python, selenium, tor

With these lines of code I am able to mask my public ip with Tor.

```py
def function():
    os.system("taskkill /f tor")
    torexe = os.popen(r'C:\Users\myuser\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor\tor.exe')
    PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r"C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://www.mikes-marketing-tools.com/whatismyip.php")
```

I need that every time I execute this function, the public ip change (with tor). How could I do that?